# Closure Instance Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Trying to figure out how to add a new player now that I've converted my ES6 module to use a closure.

So I've created a closure via factory basically:

**Player.js** - now a closure / factory

```
function Player(){
  let players = [], player = this;

  const PlayerType = Object.freeze({
    COMPUTER: "Computer",
    HUMAN: "Human"
  });

  function getPlayerById(playerId){
    const players = getPlayers().filter((player) => {
      return (player.id === +playerId);
    });

    return players;
  }

function addPlayer(name, playerType, symbol) {
    const newPlayer = Object.assign(player, { //player is undefined here
      id: null,
      name,
      symbol,
      type: playerType,
      move: null
    });

    setPlayerMoveLogic(newPlayer);
    players.push(newPlayer);
    setPlayerId(newPlayer);

    return newPlayer;
  }

  return {
    PlayerType,
    players,
    getPlayerById
  };
}

export default Player
```

So then I call it:

```
player = Player();
player.addPlayer("Computer", player.PlayerType.COMPUTER, "O");
```

Now at this point, if I look at `player1` I see that it contains all my sub functions that I returned (exposed).  But when I add players, those players have none of that because I was originally trying to do Object.assign({}...

Well {} is a completely separate object with nothing in it.  So consequently those players added have no relation to the current scope of the Player() instance I'm trying to add players to.

Notice that at the top of my function I have `player = this;`

Well after I do `player = Player();` I want to be able to work with that instance..and therefore add players to its player array.  That's what I'm trying to do here.

but it says player is undefined in my `Object.assign`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174963/discussion-on-question-by-positiveguy-closure-instance-undefined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you don't want to do it with es6 classes or old-school prototype and use a closure instead. That would not have been my choice, but, I would have said "why not?". Until you added :

> But when I add players, those players have none of that because I was originally trying to do Object.assign({}...
>
> (...)
>
> Notice that at the top of my function I have player = this;
>
> Well after I do player = Player(); I want to be able to work with that
>   instance..and therefore add players to its player array. That's what
>   I'm trying to do here.

You seem to be mixing concepts here. Your closure solution is not compatible with the use of any kind of instance referenced by `this`. Since you're calling your `Player` function without the `new` keyword.

There is no instance. There's only your function scope. And in that scope, there already is your `players` array. Just push your new player in there and you're done.

Now, you seem to want the objects contained in the `players` array and the literal object returned by the `Player()` function to expose the same function, accessing the same data through a closure.

This can be done by defining a function that returns a literal object that exposes the functions :

```
function PlayerInterface() {
    return {
      PlayerType,
      players,
      getPlayerById,
      addPlayer
    };
}
```

Your `Player()` function will return such an object. And your `newPlayer` objects will be created on such an object :

```
const newPlayer = Object.assign(PlayerInterface(), {
    id: null,
    name,
    symbol,
    type: playerType,
    move: null
});
players.push(newPlayer);
```

That way, all those objects expose the same functions, that all have the same `players` array in their scope, thanks to your closure.

Full snippet :

```js
function Player() {
  let players = [];

  const PlayerType = Object.freeze({
    COMPUTER: "Computer",
    HUMAN: "Human"
  });

  function getPlayerById(playerId) {
    const players = getPlayers().filter((player) => {
      return (player.id === +playerId);
    });

    return players;
  }

  function addPlayer(name, playerType, symbol) {
    const newPlayer = Object.assign(PlayerInterface(), {
      id: null,
      name,
      symbol,
      type: playerType,
      move: null
    });

    //setPlayerMoveLogic(newPlayer);
    players.push(newPlayer);
    //setPlayerId(newPlayer);

    return newPlayer;
  }

  function PlayerInterface() {
    return {
      PlayerType,
      players,
      getPlayerById,
      addPlayer
    };
  }

  return PlayerInterface();
}

const playerObject = Player();

// adding a player through that playerObject object
const computerPlayer = playerObject.addPlayer("Computer", playerObject.PlayerType.COMPUTER, "O");


// adding a player through the newly created player, computerPlayer
computerPlayer.addPlayer("Human", computerPlayer.PlayerType.COMPUTER, "H");

// you can see that both objects share the same private data through the closure 
console.log(computerPlayer.players.length);
console.log(playerObject.players.length);
```

For what it's worth, here's how I would have done it with old school prototypes (renaming it Game to avoid confusion with actual players).

```js
function Game() {
  this.players = [];
}

Game.prototype.PlayerType = Object.freeze({
  COMPUTER: "Computer",
  HUMAN: "Human"
});

Game.prototype.getPlayerById = function(playerId){
    const players = this.getPlayers().filter((player) => {
      return (player.id === +playerId);
    });

    return players;
}
  
Game.prototype.addPlayer = function(name, playerType, symbol) {
     const newPlayer = Object.assign({}, {
      id: null,
      name,
      symbol,
      type: playerType,
      move: null
    });

    //setPlayerMoveLogic(newPlayer);
    this.players.push(newPlayer);
    //setPlayerId(newPlayer);

    return newPlayer;
  };

var game1 = new Game();
var game2 = new Game();

var comp11 = game1.addPlayer("Comp1", Game.prototype.PlayerType.COMPUTER, "O");
var hum11 = game1.addPlayer("Joe", Game.prototype.PlayerType.HUMAN, "J");

var comp21 = game2.addPlayer("Comp2", Game.prototype.PlayerType.COMPUTER, "O");
var hum21 = game2.addPlayer("Peter", Game.prototype.PlayerType.HUMAN, "P");
var hum22 = game2.addPlayer("Bob", Game.prototype.PlayerType.HUMAN, "B");

console.log(game1.players);
console.log(game2.players);
```

Comment: it's just a design choice.  Closures give me things like data hiding.  I don't like using classes, I hate that sugar in JS...it tries to go against the grain and I like to keep things simple.

Comment: I understand the design choice, until you try to work with that "instance" you mention. Either use a closure and there is no instance, or use a class / prototype.

Comment: @PositiveGuy: But your code is not simple. The fact that the value returned by `addPlayer` should have the same properties as the value returned by `Player` is already confusing. I can't tell what the code is supposed to do. Either your choice of names is bad or the logic is flawed (or if not flawed then just confusing).

Comment: it's actually a pretty common pattern. I know people who use it all the time.  I don't know a better name for the outer function that represents the module other than `Player`

Comment: I don't mind the use of this pattern. But you can't mix both patterns. If Player() returns a bunch of functions with a closure, there is no instance referenced by `this` involved.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges yea makes sense.  thanks all!  I'll see if I can come up with a better naming convention

Comment: @FelixKling...I agree it's odd to add players to a Player.

Comment: just FYI I wasn't using the new keyword in my original post so you might want to update your answer @GuillaumeGeorges

Comment: @PositiveGuy I know you weren't using new. I'm only using it in the prototype example.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges using {} does not work...remember?  I don't get the full instance of player that way.  I need to be able to access things like players (probably via a getPlayers function that I'll add) and things like GameType enum, etc on any individual player I add

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174964/discussion-between-guillaume-georges-and-positiveguy).